# Exported Jar file not executing

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar, look-and-feel

I'm working on a small application which can be found [here](https://code.google.com/p/mini-expression-evaluator/). I have one problem : the generated Jar file is not executing. I used an `Ant` script to build the `Jar` file (The script is included in the link given below). I think the problem is in the `Look And Feel` which I applied ([Synthetica Look and Feel](http://www.jyloo.com/synthetica/themes/)). I tried to add the `Jar` library of the `Look And Feel` to the generated `Jar` file but with no success.

Comment: What makes you think that it's the problem? What happens precisely when you open a command line and execute `java -jar yourJarFile.jar`?

Comment: You can see the error here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762227/java-cant-apply-java-look-and-feel

Comment: So, you already asked the same question. Don't re-ask it. Voting to close as duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with Ant build environment, but according to the stackTrace, this is because you pack jar without the used libs. After a short search I found this docs [here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html#ext-libs).

Apply to your project in order to compile jar with lib jar(s).

Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821803/creating-a-bundle-jar-with-ant) answer also shows how to compile jar with dep. libs.